# Partition function in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, path-integral, partition-function

Why does the partition function include current term in free scalar field
$$Z[J] = \int \mathcal{D}\phi \, e^{i \left(S[\phi] + \int d^4x \,J(x) \phi(x) \right)}~$$

Comment: As a terminology point, I would call $Z=Z[0]$ the partition function and $Z[J]$ a generating function.

Answer (score 1):

It's a dummy variable to use for perturbation theory. It resembles much moment generating functions / characteristic function of random variables, as in the following example -
$$M(t)=E[e^{itx}]=\langle e^{itx}\rangle\\
(-i)^n\frac{\partial^n M}{\partial t^n}\large|_{t=0}=\langle x^n \rangle$$
ans so on, there the $t$ variable has not much use (in that context), and after differentiation the function is evaluated at $t=0$. The same is done in classical Lagrangian systems without magnetic fields, when you want to get specific equations of motion, then you reverse-engineer the Lagrangian, such that after application of the Euler-Lagrange equation you get them (thus ending up with weird $xp$ terms in Lagrangians, that don't belong to kinetic nor potential energy). The units of current density is just to get proper dimensions, as the expression in within integral of Lagrangian density.

In similar manner*  -
$$\frac{\delta^n Z[J]}{\delta J^n} \large|_{J=0}=\langle \phi^n \rangle$$

Why you want to calculate something like this? Correlators like this (of higher order) are of high importance and are the main outputs of any QFT theory (even though they are degenerate in free theories), as they can be converted to scattering rates that can be compared to experimental data.

*(I used the simple trivial example just to present the point, the value itself can be regularized)